# Javascript clearInterval don't work (no errors) ; secon Interval of same parameter

Tags: javascript

with my Javascript I wan't to play a sound (with Interval) after onclick a button and stop it after the second click.

There are no errors but the Interval is still alive and when I press the button again there seems to be another Interval, so they are playing together  added.

```
var sound_status = 0;
    var aha = 0;
    var z = 9000;
    var Intervall;

    function play_sound(){
            var sound = new Audio(aha);
            sound.play();
            console.log('1');
        }

        function player(){
            sound_status++;
            if(sound_status == '1'){
                var speed = document.getElementById('metrumIN').value;
                var calc1 = speed * 100;
                var Intervall = setInterval(play_sound, 1000);
                aha = 'sound/sound1.mp3';
                console.log(z);
            }
            if(sound_status=='2'){
                sound_status=0;
                window.clearInterval(Intervall);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your first `var Intervall` is never used.

Comment: Right, and I proofed this.It's not the error

Comment: when you declare `var Intervall = ...` inside of `function player()`, that variable is scoped to the function ONLY. omit the declaration of `var` inside of `player` scope (inside the function declaration), and you will assign the interval to your globally scoped `var Intervall`, as you intended. hope this makes sense. you should read up on variable hoisting, and don't just stop at `var`. learn about `let` and `const` as well, and learn to act accordingly. 
--
also, i want to point out that timing is not guaranteed with `setInterval` or `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`. use events on the audio.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

You're redefining `Interval1` inside your `player` function by reusing the `var` keyword. Instead, just assign it:

```
// ...
Intervall = setInterval(play_sound, 1000);
// ...
```

Boom.

**Edit, for clarification:**

If you didn't have your if statements in place, you'd be able to redefine and use your variable properly (it's just bad practice to use the same name). For example:

```
var foo = 'bar';

function test() {
    var foo = 'hello!';
    console.log(foo); // would print out 'hello!'
}

console.log(foo); // would print out 'bar'
```

But with the if statements in place, the redeclaration can't be accessed "later." Hope that helps.

**Edit, again:**

@r3wt's comment explains this as well.

**Edit, yet again, per @r3wt**

- Note that JavaScript timers aren't necessarily the most reliable when you need perfect time accuracy. [See this MDN article on some gotchas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)
- You should be using events native to `Audio`, like `play`, `pause`, and `ended`. You can [see the full list of events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Events). (Usage: `sound.addEventListener('play'...`)

I'm not going to elaborate too much, you can find more info on what I just mentioned around the web.

Comment: @r3wt Absolutely!

Comment: go ahead and point out to him the problem with timings in `setInterval` for bonus points. he should be using events on the audio to loop it properly.

Comment: @r3wt Good points. Added some links for reference.  